# nextjs authentication (OAuth)

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, next.js, azure-authentication

New to next.js/react so a little confused on how to approach this:

So we have an app, that will be built on Next.js..

- we will have apis that client-side code will call to fetch server data (my assumption is source-code for these apis do not go to client-browser and stays on node server?)
- these apis will call our actual apis,

  - these will be called by using OAuth2 token received from Azure Apps (clientid/secret)

Is my assumption correct regarding api code not travelling to browser
Secondly can I retrieve application-token (using clientid/secret) using NextAuth?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Ok, from my understanding the

- /api code doesn't travel to client side (I am using getStaticProps to call services directly rather than using fetch as I need calls to be rendered on server side)
- I was able to use @azure/identity to receive token that I need to call APIs hosted outside my node.js